# How can I send two queries after each other in node and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to make an API with node, express and mysql.

I have managed to add a record to the database and it works fine with the code below

```js
Student.addStudent = (new_student, result) => {
  db.query("INSERT INTO student SET ?", new_student, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...new_student });
  });
};
```

What I would like to do is to say that if this student is a master student, that a second insert query (into a master_student table) is executed but I cannot get this to work.

I thought I would do something like this

```js
Student.addStudent = (new_student, result) => {
  db.query("INSERT INTO student SET ?", new_student, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    result(null, {
      id: res.insertId,
      ...new_student
    });
  });

  if (new_student.type == "master") {

    db.query(`INSERT INTO master_student (student_id, course) VALUES ("${new_student.student_id}", "${new_student.course}"`, new_student, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        result(err, null);
        return;
      }

      result(null, {
        id: res.insertId,
        ...new_student
      });
    });
  }
};
```

No matter what I tried, I either get an error that headers have already been sent or that it does not insert it into either table.

How can I execute the second query if a condition is met.

I am aware that the database schema might not be sensible adding the student_id and course into both tables. This is just a simplified example to show the problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use variable substitution in the second query, use `?` parameters.

Comment: You can't call `result()` twice, since you can only send one result to the client.

Comment: Why do you have `new_student` as the parameters for the second query? There are no corresponding placeholders for that in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are other issues as others said in comments. I believe your main problem here is that the two queries run concurrently and you don't have control on the which of the two runs and completes first.

In any case, `result` will be called twice and it does not look like what you expect to do with that snippet.

One option to fix the issue is to run the queries sequentially, by moving the second `db.query` into the first callback. In there also ensure to call `result` only once.

```
 Student.addStudent = (new_student, result) => {
  db.query("INSERT INTO student SET ?", new_student, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }
    if (new_student.type == "master") {

      db.query(`INSERT INTO master_student (student_id, course) VALUES (?)`, [new_student.student_id, new_student.course], (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        result(err, null);
        return;
      }

      result(null, {
        id: res.insertId,
        ...new_student
      });
    });
  } else {
    result(null, {
      id: res.insertId,
      ...new_student
    });
}
  });

};
```